# CSS pseudo element - target only current element, not descendant

Tags: css, selector, pseudo-element

How to target a pseudo element on current element but not the children's pseudo?

the html structure:

```
<label
   <input/>
</label>
```

the css code:

```
.main-0-6-18 >input::before {
    /* the pseudo on children */

    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    content: "";
    /* blah-blah */
}

.main-0-6-18::before {
    /* the pseudo on parent */

    /* affects on children too */

    content: " ";
    display: inline;
    width: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

I tried using `.main-0-6-18>::before` but it doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: don't use the same class on both

Comment: oh yeah, i forgot to remove the class on children. thank you

Comment: You may find browsers not 'allowing' pseudo element before on input element.

Comment: i set appearance:none on the input element, so it behave like regular div/span.

Answer (score 0):

As [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) says :

> In CSS, ::before creates a pseudo-element that is the first child of the selected element.

In your case, you're using the same class so it's targeting all elements with this class.

Parent pseudo element will not affect children pseudo element

```css
.parent::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.child::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```